# Matlab: load files and save into an array

Tags: matlab, readfile

I have n files, with different names (no particular pattern). but I can have a .txt file written with each line containing name of each file. how can I use matlab that reads .txt file, and stores data of each file into a different variable.

for example: my .txt file:
abcd_e_f_004556.dat
abcd_e_f_001256.dat
...
...

```
 for i = 1: n
 data{i}= "ith" line of the .txt file
 end
```

so that in the end, I have data{1},data{2} .... containing all the data from different files of .txt file.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: [Read the documentation for `load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html), it allows you to specify an output variable.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link!